# Can anyone write a prog that change the sum(1 to n) to n*(n+1)/2 automatic?

Tags: recursion, ocaml

with the rec sum:

```
let rec sum a=if a==0 then 0 else a+sum(a-1)
```

if the compiler use the tail recursive optimization,it may create a variable "sum" to iteration（when I use the "ocamlc -dlambda",the recursive still there.when I use "ocamlc -dinstr" got the assemably code,I can't read it now）

but on the book《Design Concepts of programming languages》,page 287,it can change the function to this(the key line):n*(n+1)/2

"You should convince yourself that the least fixed point of this
function is the computation csum that returns a summation procedure that,returns n*(n+1)/2 if its argument is a nonnegative integer in"

I can't understand it,the prog not Gauss!I think it can't chang the "rec sum" to n*(n+1)/2 automatic!only man can do it,right?

So how this book write here means?Is anyone know?Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your book is merely making a small point about equivalence of pure functions. Nevertheless, optimising away a loop that only contains affine operations is relatively easy.

### Equivalence of pure functions

I haven't read that book, but from the paragraph you quote, I think the book merely makes a point about pure functions. Since `sum` is a pure function, *i.e.* a function without side-effect, then in a sense,

```ml
let rec sum n =
    if n = 0 then 0
    else n + sum (n - 1)
```

is equivalent to

```ml
let sum n =
    n * (n + 1) / 2
```

But of course "equivalent" here ignores the time and space complexity, and unless the compiler has some sort of hardcoding for common functions to optimise, I'd be extremely surprised if it optimised `sum` like that.

Also note that the two above functions are only equivalent so far as they are only called on a nonnegative argument. The recursive version will loop infinitely (and provoke a stack overflow) if `n` is negative; the direct formula version will always return a result, although that result will be nonsensical if `n` is negative.

### Optimising loops that only contain affine operations

Nevertheless, writing a compiler that would perform such optimisations is not complete science-fiction. At the end of this answer you will find links to two blogposts which you might be interested in. In this answer I will summarise  how the method described in those blog posts can be applied to your problem.

First let's rewrite function `sum` as a loop in pseudo-code:

```
function sum(n):
    s := 0
    i := 1
    repeat n:
        s += i
        i += 1
    return s
```

This kind of rewriting is similar to what happens when `sum` is transformed into a tail-recursive function.

Now if you consider the vector `v = [s, i, 1]`, then the affine operations `s += i` and `i += 1` can be described as multiplying `v` by a matrix:

```py
s += i
[[ 1, 0, 0 ],    # matrix Msi
 [ 1, 1, 0 ],
 [ 0, 0, 1 ]]

i += 1
[[ 1, 0, 0 ],    # matrix Mi1
 [ 0, 1, 0 ],
 [ 0, 1, 1 ]]

s += i, i += 1
[[ 1, 0, 0 ],    # M = Msi * Mi1
 [ 1, 1, 0 ],
 [ 0, 1, 1 ]]
```

This affine operation is wrapped in a "repeat `n`" loop. So we have to multiply `v` by this matrix `M`, `n` times. But matrix multiplication is associative; so instead of doing `n` multiplications by matrix `M`, we can raise matrix `M` to its `n`th power, and then multiply `v` by the resulting matrix `M**n`.

As it turns out:

```
[[1, 0, 0],                [[          1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0],  to the nth =   [          n, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1]]                 [n*(n - 1)/2, n, 1]]
```

which represents the affine operation:

```
s = s + n * i + n * (n - 1) / 2
i = i + n
```

Starting from `s, i = 0, 1`, this gives us `s = n * (n+1) / 2` as expected.

More reading:

- [Using the Quick Raise of Matrices to a Power to Write a Very Fast Interpreter of a Simple Programming Language](https://kukuruku.co/hub/algorithms/using-the-quick-raise-of-matrices-to-power-to-write-a-very-fast-interpreter-of-a-simple-programming-language);
- [Automatic Algorithms Optimization via Fast Matrix Exponentiation](https://kukuruku.co/post/automatic-algorithms-optimization-via-fast-matrix-exponentiation/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a known transformation as demonstrated in Stef's excellent answer. I want to add more notes to it:

OCaml does tail recursion optimizations<sup>1</sup> in which function calls get eliminated and turned into loops, but it doesn't do this closed-form transformation which is its own thing. The transformation is available today in LLVM<sup>2</sup>, though!

Although you mentioned you couldn't read the OCaml generated <strike>assembly</strike><sup>3</sup>, I think you can still interpret enough assembly generated from the function below to see the optimization in action<sup>4</sup>.

```c
unsigned recsum(unsigned n) {
  return n ? n + recsum(n - 1) : 0;
}
```

Loops and recursive functions are normally denoted with instructions that start with `j` used in a certain way where they jump to code above them, you'll notice that `jmp` to an earlier label is emitted by gcc for reference, but clang (LLVM) does not emit any such instructions at all.

When you're writing OCaml, you'll have to do such closed-form optimization manually when needed. Not many compilers go as far as LLVM does, there are diminishing returns in doing so, and the compile times suffer with every new added analysis.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> your assumption that the `sum` function is tail-recursive is incorrect, as the function in the tail position here is `(+)`</sup>

```ml
let rec sum a =
 if a = 0 then 0 else a + sum (a - 1)
```

<sup>to make it tail-recursive, `sum` needs to be the last thing you call.

You can make it so by passing what's left to do (aka `a + ...`) as an accumulating parameter:</sup>

```ml
let rec sum r a =
 if a = 0 then r else sum (a + r) (a - 1)

let sum = sum 0
```

<sup>This works because, for addition, it doesn't matter if you calculate the result on every recursive call `1 + (... + (5 + 0))` vs after all the recursive calls are executed `5 + (... + (1 + 0))`.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> [github.com/llvm/llvm-project/.../ScalarEvolution.cpp](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/88bd2601c013e349fa907b3f878312a94e16e9f6/llvm/lib/Analysis/ScalarEvolution.cpp#L37-L58)</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> note that -dinstr dumps bytecode instructions, you want to use `ocamlopt` and `objdump` for assembly</sup>
<sup><sup>4</sup> https://clang.godbolt.org/z/rcc6jcG9T</sup>